# Cant find element in clone document

Tags: ruby, xpath, jruby, nokogiri, dup

I am using Nokogiri (1.5.9 - java) in JRuby ( 1.6.7.2 ) to copy an XML template and edit it. I'm having problems finding elements in the cloned document.

```
lblock = doc.xpath(".//lblock[@blockName='WINDOW_LIST']").first
lblock.children = new_children # kind of NodeSet or Node
copy_doc = doc.dup( 1 ) # or dup(0)
lblock = copy_doc.xpath(".//lblock[@blockName='WINDOW_LIST']").first # nil
```

When print `to_s` or `to_xml`, so `lblock` there is with `new_children`. 
Where is my mistake?

Comment: `.//lblock` means find lblock beneath the *current* node. Maybe a `dup`ed doc doesn't have a current node? Have you tried an absolute XPath instead of relative?

Answer (score 0):

I can't duplicate the problem:

```
require 'nokogiri'

new_children = Nokogiri::XML::DocumentFragment.parse('<foo>bar</foo>')
doc = Nokogiri::XML(<<EOF)
<xml>
    <lblock blockName="WINDOW_LIST" />
</xml>
EOF

lblock = doc.xpath(".//lblock[@blockName='WINDOW_LIST']").first
lblock.children = new_children # kind of NodeSet or Node
copy_doc = doc.dup(1) # or dup(0)
lblock = copy_doc.xpath(".//lblock[@blockName='WINDOW_LIST']").first # nil

puts lblock.to_xml
puts
puts doc.to_xml
```

Running that outputs:

```
<lblock blockName="WINDOW_LIST">
  <foo>bar</foo>
</lblock>

<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xml>
  <lblock blockName="WINDOW_LIST"><foo>bar</foo></lblock>
</xml>
```

That said, here's code that is cleaned up to show you some simpler ways to write it:

```
require 'nokogiri'

new_children = '<foo>bar</foo>'
doc = Nokogiri::XML(<<EOF)
<xml>
  <lblock blockName="WINDOW_LIST" />
</xml>
EOF

lblock = doc.at_xpath('//lblock')
lblock.children = new_children
copy_doc = doc.dup(1)
lblock = copy_doc.at_css('lblock')

puts lblock.to_xml
puts
puts doc.to_xml
```

Which outputs this too after running:

```
<lblock blockName="WINDOW_LIST">
  <foo>bar</foo>
</lblock>

<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xml>
  <lblock blockName="WINDOW_LIST"><foo>bar</foo></lblock>
</xml>
```

Dissecting the code:

```
lblock = doc.at_xpath('//lblock')
lblock = copy_doc.at_css('lblock')
```

These use two different ways of finding the same thing. In this case, because the sample XML was simple, I used `at`, which returns the first matching node. `at_xpath` and `at_css` work with XPaths and CSS respectively. `at` would try to figure out whether the string is CSS or XPath, and normally gets it right, though I have seen it fooled.

```
lblock.children = new_children
```

In this case, `new_children` is a String. Nokogiri is smart enough to know it should convert the string into an XML fragment before using it. This makes it very easy to modify XML or HTML documents with strings, instead of having to create DocumentFragments.